# typedef enum input

Tags: c++, enums, typedef

if we have this in c++:

```
typedef enum {Unknown,USA,Canada,France,England,Italy,Spain,Australia,} origin_t;

origin_t Country;
char *current;
cin>>current;
```

how can we set `Country` to be the c-String `current` inputed by the user?
other than comparing one by one since we have a large list?
fastest way?
thank you very much.

Comment: Side note, that will seg fault as `current` is uninitialised pointer.

Comment: Side note, it is undefined behavior, it might seg fault.

Answer (score 6):

There's no direct conversion between `enum` and `string` or `char*` in C++ as there is in Java.

An efficient way is to have a map:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef enum {Unknown,USA,Canada,France,England,Italy,Spain,Australia,} origin_t;

std::map<std::string, origin_t> countries;
countries["Unknown"] = Unknown;
countries["USA"] = USA;
//...

origin_t Country;
std::string current;
cin>>current;
Country = countries[current];
```

Note that in my sample I'm using `std::string` instead of `char*`, which is what you should do unless you have strong reasons to use `char*`.

Comment: countries["Unknown"] = Unknown;
is giving me undeclared identifier on the second one!
Ok i will use string...

Comment: OOPSSS sorry I wrote Unkown when defining the enum
Thank you very much Luchian!!!! I just started Programming. Thank you

Comment: By the way, this is the best and more efficient way?? if we have a parallel array that we want to fill where the user inputs the country for each array, we just put it in a for loop... isn't there any more efficient way?

Comment: @DaggerJay11 access for elements in a map is O(1). Any gain you might get using a different approach seems negligeable.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Access for elements in a map is O(lg n), not O(1).  However, having done this often in the past (and even written code which generates it automatically), solutions using `map` have a high constant overhead.  Most enums only have a few elements, and a simple linear search will be faster.  (If you're generating automatically, you can sort the values and use a binary search, but in my experience, it doesn't really buy you anything.  Unless your code is filled with enums of hundreds of values.)

Answer (score 0):

What I use is an array of POD structs.  The struct contains an enum and a const char * of the chars corresponding to the particular enum.  Then I use std::find to look up either the enum or char * depending on which is needed.

The advantages of the array of PODs is that everything is initialized at program load time.  No need to load a map.

The disadvantage is linear search of std::find.  But it's never been an issue since I've never had a large number of enum values.

The above is all hidded in the implementation file.  The header has just functions.  Typically one to convert from enum to std::string and another to go from std::string to enum.

Comment: I think the overhead of inserting in a map all the values once is much lower than calling std::find multiple times.

Comment: @Luchian - that would depend, of course, on how many enumerated values there are.  Also, one could sort the array manually and use a more efficient search alogorithm.  But as I've said, rarely is the number of enumerated values large in my projects.

Comment: I guess that's an option, but you have to admit it's more convenient just using a map. Much less verbose.

Comment: @Luchian I don't see how using a map is less verbose.  Your code snippet is certainly not a lot of code, but that's because you've omitted error checking (which is understandable for a code snippet).

Comment: @AnonMail This is the solution I finally adopted.  After having tried and measured the others on real code.  In fact, if there are no initializers in the enum, I'd just generate a table of `char const*`, then subtract the final index from the start to obtain the enum values.