# Convert enumeration to string

Tags: c++, boost, enums, key-value

I am trying to build a function that converts an item from an enum to its corresponding string. The enums I use are fairly long, so I didn't want to use a switch-case. I found a method using boost::unordered_map very convenient, but I don't know how to make a default return (when there is no item matching the enum).

```
const boost::unordered_map<enum_type, const std::string> enumToString = boost::assign::map_list_of
(data_1, "data_1")
(data_2, "data_2");
```

I tried to create an additional function:

```
std::string convert(enum_type entry)
{
    if (enumToString.find(entry))       // not sure what test to place here, 
        return enumToString.at(entry);  //because the find method returns an iter
    else
        return "invalid_value";
}
```

I even tried something exceedingly wrong:

```
std::string convert(enum_type entry)
{
    try{
        return enumToString.at(entry);
    }
    catch(...){
        return "invalid_value";
    }
}
```

Result: evil "Debug" runtime error.
Can somebody give me a suggestion on how to either
1) find an easier method to convert enum to a string with the same name as the enum item
2) find a way to use already built boost methods to get a default value from a hash map (best option)
3) find what to place in the test to use a function that returns either the pair of the key-value, or a different string if the key is not found in the map.
 
Thank you very much.

Comment: A switch would be less code, faster, use less memory, and easier.  Why are you doing this the hard and slow way?

Comment: See similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10141241/1320751

Comment: @MooingDuck You've a good point there.  I wonder why it didn't occur to me to use a switch when I wrote my code generator for this.  (Of course, if there are no assigned values in the `enum`, a simple `char const* []` might be faster than a switch.)

Comment: I am looking for more flexibility - though I would use a switch if nothing else works - I was hoping for more built-in methods, like check if exists, and possibly a way to reverse lookup. I didn't know it was slower than a switch case ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the conversion routine:

```
std::string
convert( enum_type entry )
{
    boost::unordered_map<enum_type, std::string>::const_iterator
                        retval = enumToString.find();
    return retval == enumToString.end()
        ? "invalid_value"
        : retval->second;
}
```

Note that if the enum contains no assigned values, a simple `char const* []` will do the trick.

Comment: `auto retval = enumToString.find();`

Comment: @jpm: Yes, but that should be the default.  Every major compiler has had that feature for 3+ years, and it's the standard now.

Comment: @MooingDuck It's not present in the compilers I normally use, at least not with the options we normally use.  It's actually still fairly rare to be able to use C++11 features.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to use this but I am getting errors: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::unordered_detail::hash_const_iterator<A,G>' to 'boost::unordered_detail::hash_const_iterator<A,G>'
binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'boost::unordered_detail::hash_const_iterator<A,G>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @emptyheaded: usually that means you had the wrong items in the `<>`, or that you forgot an include.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Fair enough I suppose, lots of companies haven't yet moved to C++11.

Comment: What must I do to get the opposite conversion ? (from string to enum) - is it possible ?
Thank you very much for the help !

Comment: @emptyheaded Re the error: In your declaration, the mapped type is `std::string const`; my code  made it `std::string` (by habit, I suppose).  Both should be identical (and your `enumToString` variable can be `const` as well, so it won't matter which you use).

Comment: @emptyheaded To get the opposite, there are two possibilities.  The first is simply to use a second map: `std::unordered_map<std::string, enum_type>`.  Alternatively: use a C style array of `struct { enum_type, char const* }`, rather than `unordered_map`, with a linear search on whichever element you have to get the other.  For enums with less than about 15 or 20 elements, this will likely be faster than `unordered_map` anyway, and it provides fully static initialization, which means that you can use it in constructors of static objects without order of initialization worries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an explict answer to your question, but I recommend using another data structure:

Use a **bidirectional map** , e. g. [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

> Boost.Bimap is a bidirectional maps library for C++. With Boost.Bimap you can create associative containers in which both types can be used as key. A `bimap<X,Y>` can be thought of as a combination of a `std::map<X,Y>` and a `std::map<Y,X>`.

With a bidirectional map (you can also implement a basic one with two `std::unordered_map` instances) you are able to:

- Retrieve an enumerator for a `std::string`.
- Retrieve a `std::string` for an enumerator.

If you encapsulate the retrieve methods in a template class you are able to minimize DRY. E. g. you can pass the enumerator/`std::string` associations via `std::pair` instances to the constructor which expects one `std::initializer_list` argument.